# Rails - Given a block of text, auto-link links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

on mysite I have the ability to add comments. Sometimes users enter comments will links (href. ...)

I would like to have those links to be clickable/linkable (a href) when the comment is displayed to users.

how with Rails 3 can I take a comment, and look for links and then wrap those links in an a href tag that opens in a new window?

Thanks

Answer (score 19):

The simplest way is to use the [`auto_link`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-auto_link) method built into rails.

Note: In Rails 3.1 auto_link has been moved into [a separate gem](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink).

Comment: ive been trying to figure out why autolink wasnt working for me for a while... its was removed in 3.1, thats why. haha thanks for saving me from more frustration.

Answer (score 2):

idlefinger's suggestion of #auto_link is perfect.  I know it's not the question you originally posed, but wanted to suggest: also check out #simple_format, which will nicely format your users' use of newlines into br and p tags.